# Email Validation from SQL Database using PHP on Register form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, email

I am having a bit of an issue with a registration form.

When I enter an new email in the database It says it's not invalid even when I throw in a existing email from the database.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
include('../admin/admin_header.php');
?>

    <div class="container" id="promptContainer">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="span6 center">
                <?php
                try {

                    $title = 'Save';

                    $email = null;
                    $password = null;
                    $username = null;
                    $confirm = null;

                    //Store Info from "Email" and "Password" form to vars
                    $email = $_POST['email'];
                    $password = $_POST['password'];
                    $username = $_POST['username'];
                    $confirm = $_POST['confirm'];
                    $ok = true;

                    //Validation
                    //If Email or Password blank, $ok = false, throw echo to user
                    if (empty($email)) {
                        echo 'Email is required<br />';
                        $ok = false;
                    }

                    if (empty($password)) {
                        echo 'Password is required<br />';
                        $ok = false;

                        if (empty($username)) {
                            echo 'Username is required<br />';
                            $ok = false;

                            if ($password != $confirm) {
                                echo 'Password must match<br />';
                                $ok = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $sql = "SELECT email FROM AccountInfo WHERE email = :email";
                    $cmd = $conn->prepare($sql);
                    $cmd->bindParam(':email', $email);

                    if (!filter_var($sql, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                        echo("$email is a valid email address");
                        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://otherurl.com">';
                        $ok = true;

                    } else {
                        echo("$email is not a valid email address");
                        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://url.com">';
                        $ok = false;
                    }

                    //Save
                    $cmd->execute;


                    //If true, Save info to vars
                    if ($ok == true) {
                        include('dbCredentials.php');

                        if (empty($user_id))
                            //Insert info to SQL DB VALUES
                            $sql = "INSERT INTO AccountInfo (email, password, username) VALUES (:email, :password, :username)";

                        //SHA512 Hash Encryption
                        $encryptpw = hash('sha512', $password);

                        $cmd = $conn->prepare($sql);
                        $cmd->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
                        $cmd->bindParam(':password', $encryptpw, PDO::PARAM_STR, 128);
                        $cmd->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);


                        //Save DB
                        $cmd->execute();

                        echo 'Registration successful.';
                    }
                } catch (Exception $ex) {
                    //Email when expection error
                    mail('email@gmail.com', 'Failed to save user registration info!', $ex);

                    header('location:error.php');
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php include('footer.php');
```

This code comes from a form and when it's submitted, It POSTS to this code.
If the information is true, It will sent information to my database to its specified columns.

What the issue is, is that when I enter info to the forms and send it, It does not check to see if the email is valid from the database.

Thank you for helping me! :)

Comment: Filter the original variable not `$sql`

Comment: And you are are doing everything in the wrong order. Looks like you dont connect to the database until after you run the first SELECT query.

Comment: Start again and this time engage brain or maybe read the manual before starting any coding

Comment: I haven't slept for 2 days because of this CMS Project. I had to make a CMS from scratch

Comment: Well based on the logic, or lack of it, shown in this script, you had better hit the sack. I hope for your sake the CMS logic was built in the first 12 hours, otherwise you just wasted 2 days

Comment: Everything is complete but the email validation part

Comment: Show us what is in `dbCredentials.php`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your `if (!filter_var($sql, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {` is not correct.
It should be  `if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {`; or fetch the email from database & then pass the email value as the 1st parameter in `filter_var()`.
Also your login is not correct.
You need to validate your email first & then check whether it exist or not in database.